# Applying CSS stylesheet only to active component in React JS(duplicate but the answer are not satisfactory please suggest )

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know the question is duplicate but here are my explanation about the question :
if i have a simple .css file for a specific template and i want to load that file when that component load, is this possible? not like the variable or object way like the answer are given. 
my opinion are if the template css are really big then this is very tedious task. Like in angular we can add .css files for specific component and that load with prefix and allow that css to that component. 
please suggest if any.
I will close this once, i will get the appropriate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this concept answer that i am looking for there are multiple way to do this:(You can google these for more details description).

1. Can Use Radium CSS concept for that.
2. BEM CSS design concept.
3. CSS Module (create react App CSS module).

Please let know what more we can do.
Thanks,